# Is it possible to write into an external library on android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to add a function into my firebase-messaging librady.The file is not writable.Is it possible somehow to write in it?[image]

Comment: with Kotlin you can write extension methods.

Comment: You cannot modify decompiled code and expect the library to just pick that up. But this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Describe what you're trying to accomplish instead of (just) how you're trying to accomplish it.

Comment: Good point @ZUNJAE. As long as you're not trying to replace the existing methods, an extension method might work. Feel like writing it up as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that. If you want to add a method to FirebaseMessagingService, make an abstract class that extends FirebaseMessagingService and extend that class in your implementations.

```
public abstract class BaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public void yourMethod() {
    }
}
```

---

```
public class YourActualMessagingService extends BaseMessagingService {
    //...
}
```